# Get Sharepoint list column names using AJax

Tags: jquery-ajax

I want to get all the list column names in alert using the Ajax. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using following REST URL --

```
https://abcd.sharepoint.com/sites/RohitW/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false
```

Below is the full code :

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false";

getFields(url).then(getFieldsSuccess, getFieldsFail);

function getFields(url){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

function getFieldsSuccess(data){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(K, V){
        alert(V.Title);
    })
}

function getFieldsFail(err){
    // error callback
    debugger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharePointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#get) JavaScript library. Easy to use and really good.

Here is an example how to get field information at list.

[image]